# Poll redux saga with race condition and exit with return value

Tags: javascript, react-redux, es6-promise, redux-saga, saga

Using below approach to call polling, "task" is polling and which will trigger "cance_task" action to exit the loop.
How to return value from "task" ? should I replace calling "cancel_task" with return value ? OR its possible to return value as well using "cancel_task" to exit the 'race' ?

```
import { race, take, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* pollTask() {
  while (true) { ... 
   //to complete/cancel loop, triggering yield put({type:'CANCEL_TASK'});
   // is it possible to 'return' as well along with 'cancel_task' here ?
}
}

function* watchStartBackgroundTask() {
  while (true) {
    yield race({
      task: call(pollTask),
      cancel: take('CANCEL_TASK')
    })
  }
}
```

How to return value from "pollTask" and receive the result at caller level like below,
`const pollStatusResult = yield call(watchStartBackgroundTask);`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the result of `race` effect to determine if it was cancelled or not. Also, hard to tell without knowing more of your code, but I think you don't need the while cycle in both sagas. E.g. having a new race effect for each polling instance and getting the last uncancelled result could look like this:

```js
function* pollTask() {
  yield delay(1000);
  return Math.random();
}

function* watchStartBackgroundTask() {
  let lastResult = null;
  while (true) {
    const raceResult = yield race({
      task: call(pollTask),
      cancel: take("CANCEL_TASK")
    });
    if (raceResult.cancel) return lastResult;
    lastResult = raceResult.task;
  }
}

function* rootSaga() {
  const result = yield call(watchStartBackgroundTask);
  console.log("Result> ", result);
}
```